# Can't login with alfresco default credentials

Tags: alfresco

After installing Alfresco with Docker Compose and after installation it give me some default credentials. But when I use it for login, an issue appear : Your credentials were not recognized or Alfresco Content Services may not currently be available. Please I begin in Alfresco administration and I need your help. Thank's

NB : all containers are up in docker compose

I expect login succefully.

Comment: There must be some problem in way how you run containers. Are all logs without error? From what source you have docker compose? Did you follow official documentation? https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/containers/docker-compose/